# Dúvida com uso do Optional

Tags: java

Estou tentando usar essa classe optional para pegar os dados com null, mas retorna erro.

Na classe principal, uso o for com esse método.
Profissao e composicao de pessoas.

```
for(Pessoa p : pessoas) {

        Optional<Profissao> temNome = p.profissao.getNomeP();
```

Se usar como String

```
Optional<String> temNome =Optional.ofNullable(p.profissao.getNomeP());
```

funciona, mas nao entendi a diferença

Comment: Se você fizer assim `p.profissao.ifPresent(prof -> System.out.println(prof.getNomeP()));` mostra o nome?

Comment: Não aparece a opcao do ifPresent, voce quis dizer assim ? temNome.ifPresent() { }

Comment: Na realidade entendi sua dúvida agora. A sua segunda opção funciona porque você está chamando por último o `getNomeP` que retorna uma `String` e não uma Profissao

Answer (score 2):

Olá!

Ao que me parece, vc está confundindo. 
Veja, vc está acessando o nome da profissão, uma string, e está esperando que o mesmo retorne o objeto pai, profissão.

```
for(Pessoa p : pessoas) {
   Optional<Profissao> temNome = p.profissao.getNomeP();
   ...
}
```

O certo aqui seria:

```
for(Pessoa p : pessoas) {
   Optional<Profissao> possivelProfissao = Optional.ofNullable(p.profissao);
   possivelProfissao.ifPresent( profissao -> System.out.println(p.getNomeP()) );
   ...
}
```

Ou:

```
for(Pessoa p : pessoas) {
   Optional<Profissao> possivelProfissao = Optional.ofNullable(p.profissao);
   if(possivelProfissao.isPresent()){
      String nome = possivelProfissao.get().getNomeP();
      System.out.println(nome );
   }
   ...
}
```

Recomendo uma lida neste artigo da [Caelum](http://blog.caelum.com.br/chega-de-nullpointerexception-trabalhe-com-o-java-util-optional/). Dá uma base legal.
A [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), embora bem completa, não será lá mto didática 
Quaisquer dúvidas, é só perguntar.

**Edição 01**

Caso vc queira retornar uma String padrão qdo não há profissão, vc poderá fazer algo assim:

```
public String temNome(Profissao profissao) {
  return Optional.ofNullable(profissao.getNomeP()).orElse("Nao tem Profissao");
}
```

O mais legal é que vc faça na sua classe pessoa, escrevendo um getNomeProfissao(), assim:

```
public class Pessoa{
   ...
   public String getNomeProfissao(){
      return Optional.ofNullable(this.profissao.getNomeP()).orElse("Nao tem Profissao");
   }
   ...
}
```

Assim você seguirá a Lei de Demeter, e não irá encadear chamadas.

Answer (score 0):

Criei um método, creio que esteja correto

```
public  String temNome(Profissao profissao) {

        Optional<String> nomeProfissao = Optional.ofNullable(profissao.getNomeP());

        if(nomeProfissao.isPresent()) {

            return profissao.getNomeP();
        }  

        return "Nao tem Profissao";

    }
```

Comment: Ser o que vc quer é saber se há profissão, o mais educado é usar o "nomeProfissao.isPresent()" e deixar a tomada de decisão pra camada de cima, deixando mais coeso.
O que vc pode fazer é encapsular na sua classe pessoa o método temProfissao(), e neste vc retorna um boolean.
no caso do metodo que vc postou, faça assim:

public  String temNome(Profissao profissao) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(profissao.getNomeP()).orElse("Nao tem Profissao");
    }